# Search and replace registry entry value using powershell

Tags: powershell, registry, replace

I'm trying to update a set of registry keys, a set of properties need to be updated with a new value based on the old value.

I tried using the following:

```
 Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\xxxxx\*.mydomain.com Uri 
      | set-itemproperty -Path { $_.PSPath } Uri -Value { $_.Value -Replace ".mydomain.com/", ".mynewdomain.com/" }
```

But that sets the value of the uri property to: `{ $_.Value -Replace ".mydomain.com/", ".mynewdomain.com/" }`

I tried:

```
 Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\xxxxx\*.mydomain.com Uri 
      | set-itemproperty -Path { $_.PSPath } Uri -Value ${ $_.Value -Replace ".mydomain.com/", ".mynewdomain.com/" }
```

And

```
 Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\xxxxx\*.mydomain.com Uri 
      | set-itemproperty -Path { $_.PSPath } Uri -Value ( $_.Value -Replace ".mydomain.com/", ".mynewdomain.com/" )
```

But that clears the value.

I want to update multiple registry values in multiple keys with as few lines as possible. I already got it working by exporting the registry, use notepad to search and replace and then re-import the registry entries, but that felt like cheating. I really want to know how I can achieve this using Powershell.

Other things I've tried: `$(...)`, `(...)`, omitting the `-Value` option you name it :S.

I tried replacing `$_.Value` with `$_.Uri` and `$_`, didn't work either.

The problem is now resolved and the answer used to give guidance on [how to update your TFS project collection settings for the new Team Foundation Services](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/11/updating-your-team-foundation-service.html).

Comment: try change `{}` in `()` for `-Value` value..

Comment: @Christian tried that, no dice. Sets the value to ""

Comment: and  $_.Value.Replace( ".mydomain.com", ".mynewdomain.com") ?

Comment: @Christian Nope: `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\xxxxx\*.mydomain.com Uri | %{set-itemproperty -Path $_.PSPath Uri -Value ( $_.Uri -Replace ".mydomain.com/", ".mynewdomain.com/" )}
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick, so I suppose %{ ... } evaluates the contents before executing?

Comment: no, it means foreach, Get-ItemProperty may pipe a list of property. with foreach, we could manipulate each item individually. $_ repreasent each pipeline item, and you should use $_.Uri to fetch the value rather than $_.Value. your could just type Get-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\Software\xxxxx\*.mydomain.com Uri | fl to see the key and values.